# Non-decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that the function $h(x) = \exp(f(x))$ is non-decreasing on the reals, where $f(x)$ is a non-decreasing function.

Obviously $\,\exp(ax)\,$ is always non-decreasing, but is there a rule that states a non-decreasing function to the power of a non-decreasing function is still non-decreasing?

Comment: yes that is the definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The composition of two non-decreasing functions is non-decreasing: to see why, observe that
if $x \leq y$, then $x'=f(x) \leq f(y)=y'$ by monotonicity of $f$. So by monotonicity of $g$, $g(x') \leq g(y')$. That is, $g\circ f(x) \leq g\circ f(y)$ as claimed.